# Inverse normalization function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As far as I know the the normalization function is capable of normalize values between 0 and 1:

> $$\frac{X - \min}{\max - \min}.$$

With this the highest value will be mapped as $1$ and the lowest as $0$.
My question is the following: is there a way to map those values in an opposite way? Briefly speaking I want to map the highest value to $0$ and the lowest to $1$.

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: Once you have a $[0,1]$ normalized function $f$, you can take $x\mapsto 1-f(x)$ to reverse the ordering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just take `1 - (X - min) / (max - min)`, or

`(max - X) / (max - min)`

Comment: great solution, I joined this community just to upvote this.